# How to get Delphi to read a logged-in webpage from the default browser - not twebbrowser

Tags: authentication, delphi, browser, passwords, twebbrowser

I am trying to read data from a webpage that requires a login. I could use twebbrowser and have the user login through that, however, the point is to not allow my app to handle any security credentials, even through twebbrowser. My hope is that the user would login on their default browser, and then my app would load the page as a logged-in user without any credentials going through my app. I swear there was a time, many moons ago, when I was able to do this. However I can't seem to get it to happen now. Is this possible? Or any other suggestions for connecting to a logged-in website without the credentials going through my app? Thanks in advance.

Additional info:
What I am trying to do is write an app that reads purchase history from a rapid-fire sale website (new item every few minutes) and keeps a running total in real time while also warning the user if something comes up for sale that they've already purchased (because the web site repeats things that didn't sell out). I prefer to keep my app as only a data aggregator, ie read-only, completely separated from logging in, purchasing, etc. I don't want people worrying about entering their password or credit card in my app.

Comment: Depending on the browser, you can have an external application connecting to it using the API the browser expose. I have done that in the past with Internet Explorer 11 which is now deprecated.

Comment: Another option which is independent of the browser is to build an http proxy (You can do that using sockets) and configure the browser to pass thru your proxy. Then you have access to everything sent and received by the browser. Things becomes more difficult when the user uses https. You'll see encrypted data passing thru. It is possible to decrypt data, but then all certificates will be invalidated and the user will receive a warning about that.

Comment: How do you ensure your program is NOT reading anything when credentials are/were entered? Either you want to be a [man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) on purpose or do [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) on purpose. What do you **really** want? Why the program at all?

Comment: If the user authenticates through an external browser, you have no way to know the session cookie, which is the information necessary to "load the page as a logged-in user".

Comment: I added some additional info to the original post - I am trying to keep the app read-only in regards to the website.

Comment: @MadMartian what you are trying to do is a very serious breach of security. No modern browser is going to make it easy/possible to accomplish this from an external app.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. I have given up on the idea and coded it using twebbrowser, which appears only to log in and then disappears. I am not saving any info (username/password). Hopefully that will appear safe enough to folks using the app.